# Correct answer but runtime error Reverse Integer - LeetCode

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code for Reverse Integer on LeetCode is not accepted.

I've checked my program could return a correct answer.

```py
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        check_num = str(x)
        flag = 0
        if(check_num[0] == '-'):
            check_num = check_num[1:]
            flag = 1

        elif (check_num[len(check_num)-1] == '0'):
            check_num = check_num[:len(check_num)-1]

        #print(check_num)

        #reverse
        time = len(check_num)
        storage = [0] * time 
        for i in range(len(check_num)):
            num = len(check_num)-i-1
            storage[i] = check_num[num]
            #print(storage[i])

        if(flag == 1):
            storage.insert(0, '-')

        #turn to string
        oneLinerString=""
        for x in storage:
            oneLinerString += x

        ans = int(oneLinerString)

        return oneLinerString

def main():
    import sys
    import io
    def readlines():
        for line in io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='utf-8'):
            yield line.strip('\n')

    lines = readlines()
    while True:
        try:
            line = next(lines)
            x = int(line);

            ret = Solution().reverse(x)

            out = str(ret);
            print(out)
        except StopIteration:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the one input case, my program returns the correct output.

```
Your input
123
Output
321
Expected
321
```

But there are errors and my code is not accepted.
What are problems and how should I fix my current code?

```
Finished in N/A
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Line 30 in reverse (Solution.py)
Line 47 in main (Solution.py)
Line 55 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Comment: what is the test case that failed?

Comment: Even the test case '123' returns to these error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an input of 0, your code will convert the input to an empty string due to:

```
elif (check_num[len(check_num)-1] == '0'):
            check_num = check_num[:len(check_num)-1]
```

You should remove this elif branch and let your final integer conversion deal with the leading zeros of the reversed number:

```
ans = int(oneLinerString)  # removes leading zeros in the reversed string
```

You also need to pay attention to the condition regarding returning 0 when the reversed number is outside the range represented in a 32 bit signed integer. Therefore a final check can be added:

```
if not -2**31 <= ans <= 2**31 - 1:
    return 0
```

Making minimal changes to your sample code, a working solution is:

```
class Solution:
    def reverse(self, x: int) -> int:
        check_num = str(x)
        flag = 0
        if(check_num[0] == '-'):
            check_num = check_num[1:]
            flag = 1

        #print(check_num)

        #reverse
        time = len(check_num)
        storage = [0] * time 
        for i in range(len(check_num)):
            num = len(check_num)-i-1
            storage[i] = check_num[num]
            #print(storage[i])

        if(flag == 1):
            storage.insert(0, '-')

        #turn to string
        oneLinerString=""
        for x in storage:
            oneLinerString += x

        ans = int(oneLinerString)  # removes leading zeros in the reversed string

        if not -2**31 <= ans <= 2**31 - 1:
            return 0

        return ans
```

Comment: I'm still trouble with understanding the part "if not -2**31 <= ans <= 2**31 - 1:
return 0". Does it mean the case "ans" was 0? 
Moreover, if I delete "elif (check_num[len(check_num)-1] == '0'):", in my understanding, there is no way for cases like '120' or '300'.

Comment: On the [Reverse Integer](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/) problem in LeetCode, look under the heading 'Note' in the tab 'Description'. That should help to understand that part. Additionally, for the case '120', this will be reversed as a string to '021' then `int('021')` will return 21.

Comment: @NPP In other words, you don't need that elif case since `ans = int(oneLinerString)` gets rid of leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Try using python to its advantage:

```
def solve():
    n = input()
    l = list(map(int,str(n)))
    l = l[::-1]

    #removing leading zeros
    i = 0
    while l[i] == 0:
        i+=1
    l = l[i:]
    n = ('').join(str(x) for x in l)
    return int(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (solve())
```

Answer (score 0):

I have converted the int to string and then the string to a list. I can reverse the list easily and then can follow the same procedure to convert the list into an int object again.

```
num=-1534236469
sign=1
if num<0:
    sign=-1
    num=num*-1 # make positive for reverse
list1=list(str(num))
list1.reverse()

numrev=int("".join(str(x) for x in list1))*sign
if numrev.bit_length()>31:
    numrev=0
```

The algorithm will take more time compared to the conventional modulus-division method.